# Clean dict column in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, json, pandas

```
I have a DataFrame like the below

A    B
1    {1:3,2:0,3:5}
2    {3:2}
3    {1:2,2:3,3:9}
```

I want the column B to have missing keys in few rows like for example 2nd row only has key 3, but key 1 and key 2 are missing. For key 1, I want to set value to 1, for key 2 i want to set value to 2 and the final dataframe I would like is`

```
A    B
1    {1:3,2:0,3:5}
2    {1:1,2:1,3:2}
3    {1:2,2:3,3:9}
```

Comment: In your question it says "for key 2 i want to set value to 2" but your expected output has {2:1} in row 2. Which one is it?

Comment: Take a look at `dict.get` and `dict.setdefault`

Comment: @jezrael Great answer. Maybe add a point for beginners that `{**{1:1, 2:1}, **x}` is not same as `{**x, **{1:1, 2:1}}` that both produce different results.+1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One idea is use `merge` of dicts, but is necessary first pass `missing` for avoid overwrite existing keys:

```
missing = {1:1, 2:2}
df['B'] = df['B'].apply(lambda x: {**missing, **x})
print (df)
   A                   B
0  1  {1: 3, 2: 0, 3: 5}
1  2  {1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 2}
2  3  {1: 2, 2: 3, 3: 9}
```

If change order values are overwrite:

```
df['B1'] = df['B'].apply(lambda x: {**x, **missing})
print (df)
   A                   B                  B1
0  1  {1: 3, 2: 0, 3: 5}  {1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 5}
1  2  {1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 2}  {1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 2}
2  3  {1: 2, 2: 3, 3: 9}  {1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 9}
```

If want more dynamic solution and add all misisng keys to same value, e.g. `1`:

```
missing = dict.fromkeys(set().union(*df['B'].tolist()), 1)
df['B'] = df['B'].apply(lambda x: {**missing, **x})
print (df)
   A                   B
0  1  {1: 3, 2: 0, 3: 5}
1  2  {1: 1, 2: 1, 3: 2}
2  3  {1: 2, 2: 3, 3: 9}
```

EDIT:

For replace values by means:

```
print (df)
   A              B
0  1      {1:3,2:5}
1  2          {3:2}
2  3  {1:2,2:3,3:9}

df['B'] = df['B'].apply(lambda x: {**dict.fromkeys([1,2,3], np.mean(list(x.values()))), **x})
print (df)
   A                       B
0  1    {1: 3, 2: 5, 3: 4.0}
1  2  {1: 2.0, 2: 2.0, 3: 2}
2  3      {1: 2, 2: 3, 3: 9}
```

Comment: what if i have to assign value to key 1 as mean? How can i solve this problem?

Comment: @viswanaththatha - Do you think all misisng keys? Then use last solution. Or do you think chnage `missing = {1:1, 2:2}` to `missing = {1:1, 2:1}` in first solution?

Comment: Lets say we have a row with{1:3,2:5}, then when finding third key, i will need to have average of 1st key value and 2nd key value so the solution will become {1:3,2:5,3:4}. Also how can we make keys in order in column for every row

Comment: @viswanaththatha - There has to be `1,2,3` keys only? if in some rows are keys `5,10` then is necessary for same values keys `1,2,3,5,10` ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225088/discussion-between-viswanath-thatha-and-jezrael).